# Do we have any idea how old Ishmael's daughter, Mahalath, was when she married Esau?

Tags: age, genesis-bereishith, esav, yishmael

Esau married Mahalath after learning that his father had told Jacob not to marry an Canaanitess. Jacob's flight to Padan-Aram took place when he was 77**¹**, so Esau was probably in the ballpark of 80 when went to Ishmael's family and took Mahalath for a wife. Ishmael had died 14 years earlier**²**, so she was a teenager at the least, if we suppose that it was possible for a man to father a child in his 130's to father a child.**³**

**¹** Jacob was 130 when he entered Egypt & Joseph 39/38(30 at his elevation to vizier, followed by 7 years of plenty and 2 years of famine before his family made the trip down). It is implied that Joseph's birth took place after Jacob had been in Haran for 14 years as this point signaled the expiration of his work for Rachel and the beginning of 6 years that he worked for Laban's cattle(Genesis 31:41). Esau & Jacob were twins, so they'd be the same age at any relevant event and therefore 77 when Jacob left for Haran(and Esau married Mahalath) 14 years before Joseph's birth.

**²** Ishmael was born when Abraham was 86(Genesis 16:16) and Isaac was when he was 100. Isaac fathered Jacob and Esau when he was 60(Genesis 25:26). Due to the fact that Ishmael died aged 137(Genesis 25:17), we may reckon that the twins were 63 when their uncle passed.

**³** If there are no gaps in David's genealogy(Nahshon - Salmon - Boaz - Obed - Jesse), then we may have a case of a line of men fathering sons at extremely advanced ages so Ishmael could've potentially fathered Mahalath towards the end of his life.

Comment: @Shmuel I haven't copy-pasted anything. My question is: How old Mahalath was when she married Esau? Everything else is to show that, at the very least, she was a teen as father demonstrably dies 14 years before her marriage took place. Edit: if youre having an issue understanding how a certain component of this post is relevant, tell me and I can edit to clarify.

Comment: What is very unclear is why the rest of the question (other than "How old was Mahalath") is relevant context. It seems irrelevant, so I'm not sure if I'm missing some important aspect of the question or if it is indeed irrelevant.

Comment: @Esther My first statement is that Esau was likely around 80 when this marriage took place. the first footnote is supposed to show this. My second footnote is to show that Ishmael had died 14 years earlier, so that she was at least a teen. the third footnote is to allow for the possibility that Ishmael fathered a daughter very late in life. If the footnotes are confusing enough to warrant to comments about them, then perhaps I should delete them?

Comment: Why assume she was a teen at time of the marriage ? Given the age of Esav I would assume she was a lot older

Comment: @Schmerel I wrote that she was, at least, a teen as her dad had died 14 years earlier. Women in the ancient world usually married in their teens though.